# Way around getting "ON" value overwritten when writing LEFT JOINs with same column name

Tags: mysql

Whenever I have two tables I want to join where some of the rows will have matches and some won't, I can't figure out how to get around the issue of the column I'm using for the ON condition getting overwritten with '' when it doesn't have a match.

Here is an example query:

```
SELECT * FROM kickstarter 
LEFT JOIN user_kick_ratings 
ON kickstarter.project_id=user_kick_ratings.project_id 
WHERE rating>=1
```

Now wherever there is a row from 'kickstarter' where there isn't a matching row from user_kick_ratings, the project_id gets overwritten to ''. The only ways around this I know right now are a) make the id column names different or b) name aliases in the column select area which would force me to name every column I need, which is a lot.

I don't like either of those options, optimally. Is there a way I can use a different type of join or rearrange my query so that the project_id from the main table (kickstarter) is always there?

edit: I'll add that I DO need every row from 'kickstarter' that matches the query, but that there won't always be a corresponding row for the second table, if that wasn't already clear.

Comment: `the project_id gets overwritten` means? project_id of which table?

Comment: Why would you be using a LEFT JOIN here when you are requiring a value of rating that is >= 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, and it's so simple! Just use RIGHT JOIN and flip the table order. Even though it's simple, I hope this helps someone one day.

```
SELECT * FROM user_kick_ratings 
RIGHT JOIN kickstarter 
ON kickstarter.project_id=user_kick_ratings.project_id 
WHERE rating>=1
```

Comment: This is very strange that it worked, because your query looks the same. You are still outer joining on the same tables and conditions. The difference is probably that the filtering for `where rating >= 1` is happening *before* the join, so you don't experience the problem I described in my answer.

Comment: That's exactly what happened. Take a look at the `EXPLAIN` output for the two different queries. In this case, the `WHERE` filter occurs first on the user_kick_ratings table since you chose a `RIGHT JOIN`: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/18f203/1

Answer (score 1):

The cause of this has to do with the order of query execution. The query will first join all rows (regardless of a match, since it's a left join) and then it will filter out rows that don't meet the condition `rating >= 1`, effectively dropping any rows that didn't have a match in the first place.

To correct this, you need to change your join to only join when rating >= 1. This way, you can still get all rows from the first table, and only get matches from the second table that you need. Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM kickstarter k
LEFT JOIN user_kick_ratings ukr
ON k.project_id = ukr.project_id AND ukr.rating >= 1;
```

As far as the overwritten id, you should instead rewrite your query to only select relevant columns. There's no need to select `project_id` from both tables, since they are always the same. You should select it from the table that is guaranteed to have a value; In this case, kickstarter:

```
SELECT k.project_id, k.stuff, ukr.rating
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 1):

### For simple cases:

Instead of doing a `SELECT *`, you can use

```sql
SELECT table2.*, table1.*   -- notice the reverse order!
FROM table1 
LEFT JOIN table2 .....
```

They overwrite each other in the order of reference.
So now you got the id from `table1`.